# Is there a generally accepted pythonic syntax for modifying a generator's values?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a generator gen. Is there a more pythonic or simpler way of modifying gen's values than the example I have provided?

```
def genwrap(gen):
  for value in gen:
    yield(somefunc(value))

gen = somegenerator
for x in genwrap(gen):
  print x
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's actually applying a function that already exists, use `map`. Otherwise, this is fine, and can be shortened to a generator expression if it's simple enough (e.g. `(x + 1 for x in somegenerator)`).

Comment: Or `itertools.imap` on 2.x.

Answer (score 1):

```
def genwrap(gen):
  return (somefunc(val) for val in gen)
```

Answer (score 0):

The parentheses are not needed in the `yield` statement:

```
def genwrap(gen):
    for value in gen:
        yield somefunc(value)
```